# htaccess rewrite subdomain page not found

Tags: .htaccess

my url is

```
clients.myserver.com
```

and i want my clients to be able to access their site by going to

```
clients.mysever.com/clientname
```

The .htaccess file located in clientname (the root of their site) i use rewrite for pretty URLs as such

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

This .htacess file works perfectly if the folder is not located on the sub domain. In other words, if the clients folder is located at myserver.com/clientname, every thing works fine. If it is located at clients.myserver.com/clientnamem, the rewrite doesn't work.

Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to comment out AllowOverride None in my apache default file.